# Alt tag to GetImage("NewsTeaser")

Tags: kentico, alt

Using Kentico 10. Developed by former partner who didn't add alt tags to news article teaser images.

```
<div class="news_item">
  <%# IfEmpty(Eval("NewsTeaser"),  GetImageByUrl("~/media/Images/Home2018/NewsDefault.jpg"), GetImage("NewsTeaser")) %>
  <div class="news-title"><a href="<%# GetDocumentUrl()%>"><%# Eval("NewsTitle") %></a></div>
  <div class="news-summary"><%# Eval("NewsSummary") %></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about using one of the overloads with the alternate text parameter as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/writing-transformations/reference-transformation-methods)?  You would need to specify the dimensions though...

<%# GetImage("NewsTeaser", 200, 200, 100, **"image alternate text"**) %>

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using GetImage, you may be able to use GetFileUrl instead and build the `<img>` tag yourself. Something like:

```
<%# IfEmpty(Eval("NewsTeaser"), GetImageByUrl("~/media/Images/Home2018/NewsDefault.jpg"), "<img alt=\"\"" + Eval("NewsTitle") + "\" src=\"" + GetFileUrl("NewsTeaser") + "\"/>") %>
```

Summarized from [here](https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/getimage)